# Register a callback function for the connected event

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I´m looking for a way to register a callback function to get the **connected event**. I found the `zmq_cxt_set_monitor()` at the [zmq hompage](http://api.zeromq.org/3-3%3azmq-ctx-set-monitor).

But i can´t find an implementation for this monitor at the **node.js** library

Sry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

The main [zmq library](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node) for node.js doesn't return a callback function on the connect method, though it does for bind.

Some of the examples provided by that library erroneously show the connect method returning a callback, however you can see for yourself [here](https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/blob/master/lib/index.js#L253) that it doesn't.

Comment: So does that mean the connect method is synchronous? How can I make sure I do something only after connection has been connected?